# How does current flow with external battery for DC motor and transistor

Tags: arduino, transistors, batteries

I am very new to electronics, so bear with me.

My goal is to trigger a 6V motor from an Arduino board. I understood that for this purpose, it is better to use a separate power source for the motor and I should be using a transistor or mosfet as a switching mechanism.

I have found quite a few guides where it is explained to connect the base of the transistor to an IO pin, the collector to the + of the battery, and the emitter to ground. The motor would go between the battery and the transistor.

Then it seems like I should wire the - of the battery to ground, and thats the part I do not understand. With such a construction, there is a mix of 6v from the battery, and 3.5V of the arduino, "sharing" ground. I can not get my head around the fact that the - pole of the battery is still 6V.

So my main question: Does this all make sense, or did I misunderstand something, and will I fry my toys?
And secondary: How does that work?

Comment: Show a schematic diagram of what you propose please. I ask this not because I can't read your words but, to reduce ambiguity in what you say. In other words, **your description** is just not making sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usuall circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flh9gx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You must connect the ground side of all power supplies together.  Current from both the 6 V battery and the Arduino will flow in the emitter connection.

Comment: So does that just "naturally" even out the current amongst the power supplies? You can not accidentally somehow push more to the ground of the arduino, or the battery than its designed to?

Comment: Current from the 6 V battery only flows in the right-hand loop: battery, motor, and transistor, and back to the battery, while current from the Arduino only flows from the Arduino throught the resistor, transistor base-emitter junction, and back to the Arduino.  There is no conflict between the two currents flowing out the transistor base to the common connection point.

Comment: @W.Goeman There are ways to provide isolation between the two so that you don't need a common ground, and that may be needed in some applications (particularly when the supply for the motor is high voltage or otherwise potentially hazardous, or where there are good reasons to not have the devices share a ground), but this isn't one of them. If you look at KCL you'll see that there's no way any current from the motor supply can "leak" into the Arduino, assuming ideal components.

Comment: The only "evening out" there is taht all the Grounds are the same potential. The left hand loop is powered by the Arduino's 3V3, the RH loop by the 6V battery. The two loops are only very weakly connected by Q1's tiny base current (in a MOSFET, not even that much).

Comment: A rule of electronics you should know ... ALL CURRENTS WILL RETURN TO THEIR SOURCE.